# Dragon NaturallySpeaking special character entry - arrows

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

In my notes, I often use special characters such as `↑ ↓ → α β` among others. Is it possible to make Dragon enter these characters?

For example if I said `up arrow Dow Jones` Dragon would produce `↑ Dow Jones`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by going to Vocabulary > "Add new word or phrase" and setting the "written form" to the special character you want and training a "spoken form" that work for you. I just tried this using ↑ and "up arrow" and it worked.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the character in? When I do that I get a "?" Also, what version of Dragon are you using? I'm on 11.5, Windows 64 bit machine.

Comment: Yes, I copied it directly from your post and pasted it in the "written form" field. I'm running DNS 13 Pro, Win8.1 Pro x64.